# StanfordNER and Celery - how to increase performance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have a software written in Python 2.7 that makes heavy use of Celery. I now added NER support using StanfordNER, and I want to know how I can increase performance when tagging multiple documents; each tagging task runs on a new worker.

I implemented the StanfordNER like so:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
class NETagger(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        model = '/opt/Projects/nlp/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers/german/german.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz'
        jar = '/opt/Projects/nlp/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner.jar'
        self.tagger = StanfordNERTagger(model, jar, encoding='utf-8', java_options='-mx8000m')

    def assign_tags(self, file):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            tokens = f.readlines()
            ne_result = self.tagger.tag(tokens)

        [... write ne_result to file ...]
```

And this is what happens in Celery. I have one task, that queues up one subtask for every file that will go through the NER:

```
nertask = ExperimentalDataminingNER()
tagger = NETagger('path/to/files')

for file in 'path/to/files':
    [... create the task context ...]
    nertask.apply_async((context,), queue='default', task_id=id)
```

And the subtask does only this (the lines I stripped have no impact on the NER):

```
class ExperimentalDataminingNER():
    [...]
    tagger.assign_tags(input_file_file)
```

Basically, every document I have is being tagged on a single worker. I queue them up, the workers do their work and do it fine.

My problem: If I do not use Celery, and just out-of-the box StanfordNER, on my machine it takes 4-7 seconds to process one file. When running four of those NER tasks at the same time (I have four workers), each of them takes between 12 and 18 seconds. While I'm overall still faster using Celery, I wonder if I might have introduced some kind of artificial bottleneck somewhere? Or is it so resource-heavy that there is no way around it?

I'm using `ntlk` by the way.

**EDIT**

I tried running four parallel instances of StanfordNER outside of Celery, and the result was the same, I noticed a drastic increase of time needed for each file.

I also noticed that my measurement was off for the standard implementation, it's actually 4-7 seconds (edited it now), which is kinda bad for the Celery implementation.

Comment: have you tried to run 4 parallel NER processing manually outside celery?

Comment: No, will do it now and let you know how long it takes.

Comment: Not familiar with the toolboxes, but: if the StanfordNER is implemented already in parallel for a single document, having 4 workers launching different instances will just make them block one to each other, and that might be the reason you don't see a bigger speedup.

Comment: Edited my question. I don't know enough about the StanfordNER to answer your question about the parallel processing, sorry.

Comment: If outside celery the parallel processing takes more than in single process it means that NER is probably a RAM/CPU consuming task. Unfortunately I don't know this tool but you can try to measure your pc performances while running the computation.

Comment: What is celery? Can you post a link to the library? Are you talking about http://www.celeryproject.org/ ?

Comment: Can you post a larger sample of your code, especially how you import and initialize the celery instance? It's kind of hard to understand what might cause the bottleneck without looking at the full code.

Comment: Yes, this is celeryproject.org. I put more code into my question, hope this helps.